# How do I import Django models into python file?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model which stores inputs from a form, now that I have the data stored in Django I need to import those models to a python file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage),

> If you’re using components of Django “standalone” – for example,
> writing a Python script which loads some Django templates and renders
> them, or uses the ORM to fetch some data – there’s one more step
> you’ll need in addition to configuring settings.
>
> After you’ve either set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or called configure(),
> you’ll need to call django.setup() to load your settings and populate
> Django’s application registry. For example:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from myapp import myapp_defaults

settings.configure(default_settings=myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
django.setup()

# Now this script or any imported module can use any part of Django it needs.
from myapp import models
```

Comment: Where is the defaults file, when I import it, its not found.